# Understanding the Object.create function of JS

Tags: javascript, browser-console

I created a normal JS object

```
var person1 = {
name:"ABCD"
}
```

And then created another Object person2 as

```
var person2 = Object.create(person1)
```

Now in browser console when I type

person1 - it gives me the object definition. 
But when I type person2 - an empty object is printed (i.e {}) though person2.name returns ABCD.

Any thoughts on what is happening here.

Comment: name property comes from the prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`person2` is empty, since you've never assigned to any of its properties; in the console, you have to expand the `__proto__` property to get to the prototype of the object, to see what it inherits from.

[image]

When typing code in a script (not in the console), although you can use `__proto__` to access the prototype:

```js
var person1 = {
  name:"ABCD"
};
var person2 = Object.create(person1);

console.log(person2.__proto__ === person1);
```

it's deprecated, it's preferable to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```js
var person1 = {
  name:"ABCD"
};
var person2 = Object.create(person1);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(person2) === person1);
```